# Where to find the type representing natural numbers?

Tags: scala

Does Scala have something like natural numbers type `(0, 1, 2, ...)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers library [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) has a `Natural` [class](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/math/Natural.scala) that would be worth a look before writing your own.

To go for a test drive make a `build.sbt` file with the line `libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "spire" % "0.10.1"` in it and run `sbt`. In the `sbt` shell run `console` then `import spire.math._`.

Now you can try things out:

```
scala> Natural(3) / Natural(2)
res0: spire.math.Natural = 1
```

And so on.